# Pass IAM to Lambda through API gateway and send message to SQS using passed IAM

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-api-gateway

I want to publish to SNS or send message to SQS from Lambda using the caller identity that came through API Gateway.

In our case we receive a message and an array of queues through API Gateway. Lambda gets the message and start sending it to different queues mentioned in the message itself. The caller may or may not have access to the actual queue specified in the request. How can we make sure each caller is only able to send their own queue?

Callers may send name of a queue that they don't have access to it, I want use the caller identity inside lambda for sending messages.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use caller credentials from within your Lambda integration. Your lambda will always use the credentials from the role assigned to your Lambda function. You can use the $context.identity in your API Gateway transformation to supply the caller to your Lambda function and then make a decision in your Lambda whether or not the caller has access.

You can alternatively setup your API Gateway to call SNS/SQS directly via the [AWS service proxy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-aws-proxy.html) with caller credentials enabled. This would ensure that the callers have permissions. You do lose some flexibility the Lambda function offers, but this is the trade-off you must consider.